# Find duplicate values in two columns, only highlight in one column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

I need to search for duplicate values in two columns in excel, but i only want the cells of one column to show if there are duplicates. Any idea how i can do that?

Comment: `COUNTIFS` should work.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say column A holds some values and you want to highlight values from Column A that exist in column B.

You need to create a conditional formatting rule based on a formula:

[image]

```
=COUNTIF($B$1:$B$6;A1)>0
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### FIND DUPLICATE VALUES IN TWO COLUMNS, ONLY HIGHLIGHT IN ONE COLUMN

Highlighting duplicate values in one column based on two columns, you need to use conditional formatting with a formula based on the `COUNTIF()` and `AND()` functions.

In the screenshot shown below, the formula used to highlight duplicate values is

```
=AND(COUNTIF(Range_1,B3),COUNTIF(Range_2,B3))
```

The above formula uses two named ranges, **"Range_1"** `$B$3:$B$13` & **"Range_2"** `$D$3:$D$11`.

The essence of using this formula is the `COUNTIF()` function, which returns a count of each value in both range inside the `AND()` function

```
COUNTIF(Range_1,B3) --> Count in Range_1

COUNTIF(Range_2,B3) --> Count in Range_2
```

`COUNTIF()` will either return `0` (evaluated as `FALSE`) or a `+ve` number (evaluated as `TRUE`) for each value in both ranges!

If both counts are `+ve` (i.e. non-zero), the `AND()` function will return `TRUE` and trigger the conditional format!

Note: Only **Range_1** was selected when the **Conditional Formatting Rule** was applied.

[image: CONDITIONAL_FORMATTING]